# Which language is the following program written in?

Tags: programming-languages

```
ROOTPROC VarUse
PROC VarUse
ROOT Cfile;
1 {
2 [
3 (?NameRef
4 (IF (AND (HAS-TYPE $parent Assignment) (IS-EQUAL $slot ``lhs''))
5 (THEN (PRINT stdout "Variable %s defined at %s" $token $location))
6 (ELSE (PRINT stdout "Name %s accessed at %s" $token $location))))]
7 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Gen++](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~devanbu/genp/), application generator for C++.

Answer (score 1):

GEN++ an analyzer generator for C++

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Genoa language specification.

(Don't ask me for details, all I did was googling "HAS-TYPE ROOTPROC IS-EQUAL".)

Comment: Deferring to vpit3833, he got the link to go with the information.